# How to set QTreeWidgetItem as not Editable

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

After creating an item and setting it to as being editable:

```
item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```

I want to reset all item's flags and set this item back to non-editable.

What would be correct syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to perform the inverse operation you did as the Qt flags are 
bitwise.

```
item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```

The default value for flags is `Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled` in case you want to set back the default behavior for the QTreeWidget.